# Is it faster to programmatic join tables or use SQL Join statements when one table is much smaller?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, join

Is it faster to programmatically join tables or use SQL Join statements when one table is much smaller?

More specifically, how does grabbing a string from a `hashmap<int, string>` of the smaller table and setting its value to the objects returned from the larger table compare to pre-joining the tables on the database? Does the relative sizes of the two tables make a difference?

***Update:*** To rephrase my question. Does grabbing the **subset** of the larger table (the 5,000 - 20,000 records I care about) and then programmatically joining the smaller table (which I would cache locally) out perform an SQL join? Does the SQL join apply to the whole table or just the subset of the larger table that would be returned?

SQL Join Statement:

```sql
SELECT id, description
FROM values v, descriptions d
WHERE v.descID=d.descID
AND v.something = thingICareAbout;
```

Individual Statements:

```sql
SELECT id, descID
FROM values
WHERE v.something = thingICareAbout;

SELECT descID, description
FROM descriptions d;
```

Programmatic join:

```java
for (value : values){
    value.setDescription(descriptions.get(value.getDescID))
}
```

***Additional Info:*** There are a total of 800,000,000 records in the larger table that corresponding to 3,000 values in the smaller table. Most searches return between 5,000 - 20,000 results. This is an oracle DB.

Comment: Get some numbers. It looks simple enough to implement both, so do that and then run a unit test with timing around it to get min/max/average timing.

Comment: The database engine is most likely smarter than you. A striking size difference is not a reason to do things yourself. It might be the opposite.

Comment: Relational databases are generally very good at their job, which is to store and retrieve related data.  But when it doubt, try it and see what you get.

Comment: It's nearly always faster to do something on db side. It's optimized, and that's why you got a db: to avoid a big part of this mess.

Comment: Performance is a curious beast, what performs well one day does not the next. Generally you would do the join in the database unless there is good reason not to. This good reason could be network bandwidth, depth of use in the code call stack, load on the database, resource distribution for the architecture, most of the reasons you would do it are out of your control normally. It is not hard to make your code perform better than the database for specific situations, equally it is not hard to make it perform worse. The better approach is to make your code maintainable.

Comment: The database will optimize the the join, while your code must iterate over each row in order to join.  The database will always be faster at doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, joining tables like this is the sort of operation that SQL databases are optimized for, so there is a good chance that they're fairly hard to beat on this sort of operation.

The relative size of the two tables might make a difference if you attempt to do the join "manually" as you have to factor in the additional memory consumption to hold the bigger table data in memory while you're doing your processing.

While this example is pretty easy to get right, by doing the join yourself you also lose a built-in data integrity check that the database would give you if you let it do the join.

Comment: (Also, I wouldn't want to be around while fetching 800 million records :D)

Comment: @pst, that would give one a chance to brew (and possibly grow and roast) some really awesome coffee :).

Answer (score 9):

Don't even think it. The database can do things locally at least as fast as you can, and without having to ship all the data over the network.

Answer (score 2):

Probably SQL would do the work faster. From my understanding, if you do it in your program then it would have to load the 800,000,000 records from the database into memory for your application, then the 3,000 for the small table, then match each record, discard almost all of them (you're only expecting a couple of thousand results) and display to the user.

If you put indexes on the right columns in oracle (descID in both tables) then it would be able to find the joining records very quickly and just load up the 5,000-20,000 that you're expecting.

That said though the easiest way to find out is to test both out and take numbers!

Comment: "Probably"!? Don't sound so unsure!

Comment: I can't imagine a case when it would be faster, but you never know. It might be faster in the long run to load all locally if you keep querying for slightly different data, which might also depend on the size of each of the records.

Answer (score 2):

If you do the join in memory, you will need to download 800,000,000 + 3,000 records.  If you do the join in the database you will need to download 5,000 - 20,000 results each time.  Which sounds faster to you?  Hint: If you do 100,000 searches the first option *might* be faster.